# Text based control algorithim for modelica

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I am trying to model a microgrid simulation using the modelica buildings library. I am using OMEdit to model the system, but would prefer to write the code for the control algorithm for the bi-directional battery inverter in text format as I come from C/Python background and find it easier to follow compared to a visual system. I wrote this code:

```
model battery_control
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput SOC;
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput inverterInput;
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput meterInput;
equation
  if (meterInput <= -20) and (SOC > 20) and (meterInput >= -100) then
    inverterInput = abs(inverterInput + 20);
  elseif (meterInput >= -100) and (SOC > 20) then
    inverterInput = 100;
  elseif (meterInput >= 5) and (SOC < 90) and (meterInput < 100 ) then
    inverterInput = -1 * (inverterInput - 5);
  elseif (SOC < 90) and (meterInput < 100 ) then
    inverterInput = -100
  else
    inverterInput = 0;
  end if;
end battery_control;
```

However, OMEdit does not let me save this code. I am not sure what is wrong. Basically, I want to create a block that connects to the input and ouput, but it is text-based control. Also, is it possble to run python code in modelica, not the reverse(run modelica in python: PyFmi). Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply forgot a semicolon at line 13. It should be:

```
    inverterInput = -100;
```

This can be identified by checking the messages in the message browser, where OMEdit reports a syntax error. If you click the linked error message, it directly sends you to line 14, where the error is detected.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's a missing semi-colon after `inverterInput = -100`. The risk of writing textual code are such trivial errors.

I don't know what error message OMEdit gives, but Dymola says:

```
else (line 14, column 3: battery_control)    
 Expected one of:  
  ";" 
  "," 
  ...
```